# How to get User ID from CustomUser on Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

usign Spring Security ,I'm trying to get the user id from my CustomUser instance returned from loadUserByUsername method on my CustomUserDetailsService, like I do to get get the Name (get.Name()) with Authentication. Thanks for any tips!

This is how I get the current name of logged user:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = authentication.getName();
```

And this is the CustomUser

```
public class CustomUser extends User {

    private final int userID;

    public CustomUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
                      boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                      boolean accountNonLocked,
                      Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, int userID) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

And the loadUserByUsername method on my Service

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Usuario u = usuarioDAO.getUsuario(s);

    return new CustomUser(u.getLogin(), u.getSenha(), u.isAtivo(), u.isContaNaoExpirada(), u.isContaNaoExpirada(),
            u.isCredencialNaoExpirada(), getAuthorities(u.getRegraByRegraId().getId()),u.getId()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Authentication authentication = ...
CustomUser customUser = (CustomUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
int userId = customUser.getUserId();
```

You have to add the `getUserId()` getter method if you don't already have it.

Comment: `Principal` can be injected.

Comment: Injection via method parameter: @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser